# PHP only read the first value of input array dynamic created

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Sorry for the bad English, I'm still learning...

Well i have in HTML a table with only

```
<tr id="linha_1">
    <td><input type="text" name="nome_cor[]" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="cod_cor[]" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="file" name="img_cor[]" /></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Remover" id="remove" onclick="$.removeLinha(this);" /></td>
</tr>
```

I also have a JS script that adds new rows to this table, this script copy the first line, so the user can add more colors...

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var row_limit = 0;
    $('#add').click(function()
    {
        var linha_total = $('tbody#repetir tr').length;
        if (row_limit == 0 || row_limit > linha_total)
        {
            var linha = $('tbody#repetir tr').html();
            var linha_total = $('tbody#repetir tr').length;             
            var linha_id = $('tbody#repetir tr').attr('id');                
            $('tbody#repetir').append('<tr id="linha_' + (linha_total + 1) + '">' + linha + '</tr>');
        }
        else
        {
         alert("Desculpe, mas você só pode adicionar até " + limite_linhas + " linhas!");
         }                      
});
```

Using malsup form plugin to send the data via post:

```
$("#send").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#form-tapete").ajaxForm({        
        // validation and progress bar (*not important to the question i think*)
    },
    url: 'dados-tapete.php',
    resetForm: false
 }).submit();
```

I'm trying to read this in PHP with this code:

```
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($cod_cor); $i++)
{
    $path_cor = "catalogo/tapete/cor/";
    $path_cor = $path_cor.basename($_FILES["img_cor"]["name"][$i]); 
    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img_cor"]["tmp_name"][$i], $path_cor)) 
        die("Ocorreu um erro ao enviar a imagem, tente novamente!"); 
    $cor_img_name = "catalogo/tapete/cor/".$_FILES["img_cor"]["name"][$i]; 
    $cadastra_cores = $con->sql_query("INSERT INTO tape_cores VALUES ('$nome_tapete','$cod_cor[$i]','$nome_cor[$i]','$path_cor')"); 
}
```

The PHP script can read and send the values to the database, but only the first value...
The rows that was added dynamically don't appear in the $_POST array...

I searched for this and found some asked questions here, but no solution...

Sorry for the bad English again, if you don't understand me I can try to explain in other words... thanks

Comment: show to javascript code which is generating the input fields, the input field should generate with the same parameters if you need a output in array like <input type="text" name="nome_cor[]" value="" />

Comment: i included the script that create the dynamic input wi jQuery append();

Comment: So how do you actually POST the data? You should show this code.

Comment: i send the data to php script with malsup jquery form plugin, its easy to send input files without refreshing the page, code added... thanks for your attention (:

Comment: Are you sure that your dynamic fields are truly get appended? And what is the value of `sizeof($cod_cor)` here?

Comment: when i run the page, the jquery for dynamic fields works fine, the problem is when i send it to the php... i lost the data of dynamic added inputs, can only get the data of the input added manually

Comment: Try `for ($i=0; $i < count($cod_cor); $i++)` instead of `for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($cod_cor); $i++)`

Comment: i tried, but it doesnt work too, the loop just dont do a loop, maybe the html is not recognizing the inputs dynamic created like a part of the form...

Answer (score 2):

I would use JQuery with something like this :

```
$.post( "test.php", $( "#testform" ).serialize() );
```

For Malsup JQuery, use formSerialize();

```
var queryString = $('#myFormId').formSerialize();  
$.post('myscript.php', queryString);
```

Comment: I'm sending the form with Malsup's jQuery form plugin, i have to change it?

Comment: I don't know Malsup, but regarding the doc seems possible and not so far away from the pure JQuery way : http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#api

Comment: i don't get problems to send the values via $_POST, the problem is im only sending the first value of the input arrays... thanks for the attention

Comment: If you add "echo $i;" in the for loop what result do you get ?

Comment: the "echo $i;" returns 0

Comment: You loop just one time, so your sql insert is executed just one time. As asked in another comment, your code with your "post" will be useful for us to help

Comment: i tried the serialize and formserialize methods, but it doesnt work, i also read de queryString generated and the values of the other rows isn't there... ):